# Is it possible to have a Python class decorator with arguments?

Tags: python, decorator

What I'd like to do is this:

```
@add_cache(cache_this, cache_that, cache_this_and_that)
class MyDjangoModel(models.Model):
    blah
```

But fails because it seems that the first argument is implicitly the actual class object. Is it possible to get around this or am I forced to use the ugly syntax as opposed to this beautiful syntax?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `arg_cache` definition needs to do something like:

```
def arg_cache(cthis, cthat, cthisandthat):
   def f(obj):
       obj.cache_this = cthis
       obj.cache_that = cthat
       obj.thisandthat = cthisandthat
       return obj
   return f

@arg_cache(cache_this, cache_that, cache_this_and_that)
...
```

The example assumes you just want to set some properties on the decorated class.  You could of course do something else with the three parameters.

Comment: In my opinion it would have been better to have named the argument to the nested function something more descriptive, like `f(cls)`. A little more in the way of an explanation would have been nice, too.

Comment: Wow, I Googled "class decorator with arguments" for like an hour and you make it look so simple. By the way, I called the wrapper function `arg_acceptor(cls)` to try to show that the decorator receives the arguments and the wrapper function receives the class (unlike no-argument class decorators which receive the class right away).

Answer (score 1):

Write a callable that returns an appropriate decorator.